# How do I recover my missing spooled printer files

Tags: windows-xp, printer

I hope someone can help.  For sometime I have had paper pick-up mechanism printer problems because there aren't any rubber roller spares for my A3 QMS2060 laser printer.  I have been printing urgent files with hand feeding the printer and left the others spooled and paused in the printer queue.  When I got to 391 printer files spooled and paused I invested in a new Ricoh A4 printer!  It installed and works fine.  I have since got in a muddle trying to change the spooled files to print on the new printer.  I changed the printer from the QMS one to the Ricoh in Printer & Faxes and all the 391 paused files were changed to Ricoh. When the one I tried didnt print I tried to undo what I had done. The computer locked up and I had to CTRL_DEL_Back and reboot.  Now Printer & Faxes reports 0 spooled files for both the QMS and Ricoh printers.  The reboot may have cleared the files but I haven't deleted anything or saved anything so I am hoping the file still exists perhaps as a back-up file.  A lot of downloads and work was in the spooled files!!
System XP Pro v3

Comment: Can you not just run the print jobs again from the original documents?

Comment: These files were over a year and I dont have the list to find some of them

Comment: Then if you think they may be in your backup, time to start scavenging your backup. Potentially, they're at `C:\Windows\System32\Spool\PRINTERS\` but I'm not sure if it was that in XP. Haven't seen XP in a decade.

Comment: That folder is empty:(

Comment: In all your backups too?

Comment: I cloned the disk last december and that folder contains the first 302 files.  I have copied them to a stick but not copied them yet to the HD so as to not overwrite any files.  Can you tell me how to try to recover them.  The files are in pairs and numbered.  The first of each pair is like FP0244.skd and the second FP0244.spl  the first always 7kb.  The first 302 will be numbered 0001 to 0302 so I am looking for 0303 to 0391.

Comment: Best you can do is copy like to like location & see what happens.

Comment: Well I am pleased.  I used ICareAll free version to recover most of the missing files onto a stick so as not to save them on the HD.  It recovered lots of spooled files which had been printed too.  The recovered files were easily found in the Printers Folder and using the sorting tab this gave me them in order and I recovered them, again to the stick.  Have most of the files I lost.  The fact that the names are ordered helped!

Answer (score 0):

If you have spooling directories for individual printers, they will be in the registry
at key
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Printers\your-printer`,
inside the value named `SpoolDirectory`.
So check if the old printer's files are still there.

If you find your files, and the old printer still exists (I don't remember if
XP had "Devices and Printers"), you might be able in its Properties, then in the
Ports tab to change the port to point to the new printer
(which may work better with an IP address).

Otherwise, the Recycle Bin is your last chance.